# Read response as string wininet

Tags: c++, wininet

This function creates a post request to an endpoint and receives a JSON response, the goal is to save the json data as a string.
I checked the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms906349(v=msdn.10)) docs but I can't figure it out

```
    void POST(std::string data, std::string endpoint ) 
    {
        static TCHAR hdrs[] = _T("Content-Type: application/json");
        static LPCSTR accept[2]={"*/*", NULL};
        // for clarity, error-checking has been removed
        HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(DEFAULT_USERAGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
        HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, MY_HOST, ALT_HTTP_PORT , NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
        HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", endpoint.c_str(), NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 1);
        HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), (PVOID)data.c_str() , data.length());
        // close any valid internet-handles
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to listen for a response? From the documentation it seems that `HttpSendRequest` only sends the request, but doesn't wait for a response.

Comment: how do you do that